# What is the lighting logic for the box-shadows in material design?

Tags: drop-shadow

In material design, the box shadows are defined in sets of two (https://codepen.io/sdthornton/pen/wBZdXq)

Like so (each card appears more forward than the last):

```
.card-2 {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.card-3 {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}

.card-4 {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
```

What is the logic behind the decision to have two shadows?  It obviously looks nicer than a single box shadow would, but there must be some reason why.

My current guess is that some amount of surface reflection is taken into account.  Either that or perhaps shadow fades are meant to be curved (non-linear opacity dropoff) and this was the cheapest (CPU) way to achieve that look.

What is the logic behind these design decisions?

Comment: The logic of this, and most design, was discovered by scientists and artists long before any of these contemporary things.

Anyways, I think I found what I was looking for.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbra,_penumbra_and_antumbra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Seph Reed:

The light logic as I understand it is to quantify a simple stylistic guide to achieve *both* ambient occlusion shadowing *and* direct cast shadows, which combine to indicate a "height" in "z" space off the screen towards the user, to help differentiate overlapping elements in agreement with this styleguide section.

(https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-shadows)

And this equivalent for android developers:

(https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html

Aaaaaaand... here is the ***canonical*** explanation from the Google Material guide on environment to explain ambient vs cast shadows:

https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/environment.html#environment-light-shadow

Light and shadow
Within the material environment, virtual lights illuminate the scene. Key lights create directional shadows, while ambient light creates soft shadows from all angles.

Shadows in the material environment are cast by these two light sources. In Android development, shadows occur when light sources are blocked by sheets of material at various positions along the z-axis. On the web, shadows are depicted by manipulating the y-axis only. The following example shows the card with a height of 6dp.

*Shadow cast by key light*
[image]

*Shadow cast by ambient light*
[image]

*Combined shadow from key and ambient lights*
[image]

Note that by this light logic in combination with the shadow and layering reference, this means that only those interface items whose "z" delta is small (1 layer's worth of difference) should cast a noticeable ambient shadow - if an interface element is 2 or more layers above the item receiving its cast shadow, you should not add the ambient shadow.

Comment: While researching this I have also found this :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbra,_penumbra_and_antumbra.

If you could please add the link to your answer and let people know about the scientific terms, I think it would be awesome.  Or, with your permission, I may do it myself.

Comment: Seph,

These are **not** the same concepts at all. 
I specialise in rendering, and have recently used that same wikipedia article to explain shadow drawing from a sphere here in Stack Exchange Graphic Design.
Ambient light is **not** described at all in that article - it is the light which bounces off all nearby surfaces, and which in aggregate, act like a diffuse light source aimed directly at (normal to) a given surface. If you look at the corners of a room, where the walls and ceiling come together, the slight shadows there are called "ambient occlusion".

Comment: In the case we are discussing ***here***, this is what a photographer or a renderer would call a *"two light setup"*, which includes a general ambient light and one "key" light to provide clear directional light.
The terms ubmra, penumbra and antumbra are all specific to *single light sources*, and do not include ambient light considerations whatsoever, and are therefore **not** helpful to this discussion.

Comment: For your reference Seph - that other SE GD article:

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107536/how-would-i-draw-a-shadow-from-a-spherical-object-onto-a-non-flat-surface/107548#107548

Comment: I see what you are saying, but they absolutely are useful to this discussion.  They help one understand light.  Whether it was intentional or not, the realism in material design is inherently in part of imitating real light, which has those properties.  I can not even begin to comprehend how you could consider this information "not helpful" to the understanding of shadows.

Comment: Seph, you're **absolutely** correct this helps with building a *general understanding* of light & shadow in a one primary light scenario, and *that's* generally useful to all designers, but it's literally *outside the scope* of the question you asked - *"what's the light logic for the box shadows used in material design"* - for which the **answer**, *directly from* the official Material graphic design guidelines was *"two sources, one ambient and one key"* with explanations and examples. It's tangentially relevant, I agree, but it's *not* part of the light logic in Material design. You see?

Comment: Seph, seems like this to-and-fro is getting extensive - we should probably migrate that to [Chat] {light-and-shade}Chat

Comment: I do agree with that, but I think the strict adhesion to such scoping undermines the intention of requesting such knowledge.  These questions are guidelines, touch points meant to be easily translatable.  I can not know what question to ask, but, at least when I ask questions, the intent is to learn as much as possible, not to create strict boundaries for the answers I may recieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75516/discussion-between-gerardfalla-and-seph-reed).